# Stop post update in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So, my goal is to stop a post update if the admin user doesn't fulfill certain criteria for certain post. The code I have for now (which works) is this:

```php
function stop_update( $data, $postarr) {
        if (/* condition */) {
                wp_die("UNAUTHORIZED");
        }

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'stop_update' , '99', 2 );
```

Is there a better way to do this without using wp_die?

Comment: User admin-notice actions